# $50^{th}$ digit from the left in the expansion of $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The $50^{th}$ digit from the left in the expansion of $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}$ after the decimal point.

$\underline{\bf{My\; Try}}::$ Let $\left(\sqrt{50}+7\right)^{50} = I+f$, where $I = $Integer part and $f = $ fractional part. and $0\leq f<1$

Now Let $\left(\sqrt{50}-7\right)^{50} = g$ and here $0\leq g<1$

Now $\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{50}+7\right)^{50}+\left(\sqrt{50}-7\right)^{50} = 2\left(\binom{50}{0}\cdot (\sqrt{50})^{50}+\binom{50}{2}\cdot (\sqrt{50})^{48}\cdot 7^2+..............+\binom{50}{50}\cdot 7^{50}\right)$

$\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{50}+7\right)^{50}+\left(\sqrt{50}-7\right)^{50} = $Integer quantity.

$\displaystyle I+f+g = $ Integer Quantity. and $0\leq f+g<2$ So $(f+g) = 0$ or $(f+g) = 1$

So $I=$Integer quantity or $I = $ Integer quantity$\;\;  -1$.

Now I did not understand how can i get it.

Help required.

Thanks

edited.

Comment: It's a bit easier than that: you know that $g\lt 1$ and that $I+f+g$ is some other integer, $j$ (your 'integer quantity').  Since $g\lt 1$, then it must be the case that $j$ (which is $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}+(\sqrt{50}-7)^{50}$) $=I+1$ and so $I$ is one less than this quantity.

Comment: Which digit are you looking for?  $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50} \approx 2.6\cdot 10^{57}$, so the fiftieth from the left is the hundred millions place.  It that the one you want, or the fiftieth after the decimal point.  The second is the more common question.

Comment: oh sorry actually it is  fiftieth after the decimal point. Thanks for pointing out Ross Millikan. please explain me how can i get it.

Comment: An answer was posted, then unfortunately the author deleted it when he thought he misread the problem. But in fact he got it right. I have voted to undelete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the number $N=(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}+(\sqrt{50}-7)^{50}$.

Using the Binomial Theorem, or otherwise, we can show that $N$ is an integer.

Our number $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}$ is a little **below** $N$. How much below? Courtesy of the calculator, $(\sqrt{50}-7)^{50}\approx 4\times 10^{-58}$. So the $50$-th digit after the decimal point of $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}$ is $9$.

Comment: You could replace the calculator by using $$\sqrt{50}-7=\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}+7} < \frac{1}{14}$$ so $(\sqrt{50}-7)^{50} < 10^{-50}$.

Comment: In the old days I would have used a log table. No batteries.

Comment: Thanks André Nicolas and WimC, but i did not understand the line So the $50-$th digit after the decimal point of $(\sqrt{50}+7)^{50}$ is $ = 9$

Comment: @juantheron: Think about taking away say $0.000000005$ from $17$. The first $8$ digits after the decimal point are $9$'s. In the case of our roblem, the first $57$ digits after the decimal oint are $9$'s.